# Text boxes in excel disappear when worksheet is copied into new workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

(Using Excel 2010) I am trying to copy a worksheet that has text boxes and paste it into an existing workbook.  When I copy the worksheet (CTRL+A+A or right click-copy) and paste the worksheet in the existing workbook, all the data is there except the text boxes. I have verified that the "cut, copy, and sort inserted object with their parent cells" is checked.  The object positioning is set as "move and size with cells" (but I have tried copy/paste with the other options checked as well).  If I copy/paste in the same workbook, everything copies just fine.  Also have tried selecting the text box and then selecting the worksheet but I get an error message "that command cannot be used on multiple selections".

The problem seems to be only when going from one workbook to another workbook.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I click on the tab of the worksheet I want to move and select "move or copy" and then select to move or copy to an existing workbook (selectable from the dropdown) my text boxes get moved or copied across.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I tried that and get an error message: "excel cannot insert into destination workbook because it contains fewwer rows and columns than the source workbook..." However, it will work if I choose "new workbook."  I accidentally figured out my problem yesterday.  I believe it is a bug with the new file etx .xlsx.  Text boxes will not copy into a new workbook if both files are .xlsx (the new file ext) but if both files are the old file ext .xls text boxes copy to a new workbook just fine.

Comment: This works for me even if the two files are .xlsx - More likely you are trying to move an .xlsx sheet into an old .xls workbook - then one is much bigger than the other.